# Angular2 Shopping Cart with buy now button

Tags: angular, shopping-cart

Trying to get a shopping cart add button to fill the shopping cart service which stores the array of products. The issue is, I can not up date my shopping cart list inside my shopping cart component as I can not detect when the button/or array has been filled with a new product. Which in turn does not add new products to the ngFor.

I have read stuff about change detection, zones, event emitters. Just not sure which one is the right one to use in this particular case... I have attached my code below

SHOPPING CART BUTTON COMPONENT

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, NgZone} from 'angular2/core'
import {ShoppingCartService} from './shopping-cart.service.js'

@Component({
    selector: 'add-cart',
    template:`<button (click)="addToCart(product)">ADD TO    CART</button>`,
    inputs: ['product']
})
export class AddCartComponent {

      constructor(
         private _shoppingCartService: ShoppingCartService
      ) {}

    addToCart(product: any) {

       console.log(this.product);
       this._shoppingCartService.add(this.product) 

     }

}
```

SHOPPING CART COMPONENT

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ShoppingCartService} from './shopping-cart.service.js'

@Component({
selector: 'shopping-cart',
template:`
    <div id="shopping-cart">

        <ul>
            <li *ngFor='#product of shoppingCart'>
                {{product.title}}   
            <li>    
        </ul>

    </div>
`
})

export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {

products: any[];

constructor(
    privarte _shoppingCartService: ShoppingCartService;
) {}    

ngOnInit() {

    this.products = shoppingCartService.get();

}
}
```

SHOPPING CART SERVICE

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class ShoppingCartService {

products: any[];

constructor() {

    this.products = [];

}

add(product: any){

    this.products.push(product);
}

remove(index: number) {

    if (index > -1) {
        this.products.splice(index, 1);
    }

}

clear() {

    this.products = [];

}

get() {

  return this.products;

}

}
```

Comment: How are these components related? Where is your `<add-cart>` component added?

Comment: The add cart is added into another component which is named shopping cart list

Answer (score 0):

In your ShoppingCart component, you need to iterate of `products` and not `shoppingCart`:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='#product of products'> <------
    {{product.title}}   
  <li>    
</ul>
```

Moreover you need to have the `ShoppingCartService` service to be a shared service for both components. To have no problem, be sure to have specified it when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ShoppingCartService ]);
```

Comment: Yes I add ShoppingCartService to the bootstrapping.. so have access to the service in both components

Comment: Great! Is the use of `shoppingCart` in your loop a typo in your question?

Comment: Does this fix your problem? ;-)

Comment: Will try now... not sure why but my shopping cart is not binding to the dom

Comment: Dont i need somehting to detect when a new product is added to update the product list in shopping cart component

Comment: shoppingCart is your component? You need to bind elements in the component, for example `products`...

Comment: `ngFor` will detect the updates. Since it relies on the `products` list from service. It should be automatic...

Comment: Brillant that works, did not relise that this.products = this._shoppingCartService.get(); will continue to get the products from the array. thanks for you help once again